# Repetition of divided character-chains in String java

Tags: java, vigenere

There are many questions like this one out there on stackoverflow, I know.
Despite that, I cannot seem to find a clue for a solution.

I have to write a class for a program which can decrypt Vigenere with the Kasiski test. My job is to write the class "Repetition" which finds repetitions of character-chains in a string and a lot more.

Example String s = "**abc**fghkjngf**abc**dfgkjdf**abc**"
Repetitions must be at least 3 characters long, like abc in this case. If it makes any difference, the longer the character chain the better.

I have been reading about Maps for some time now already, but the solutions I found deal with words which need to be counted, seperated by comma or space, which does not work for my String.

I am not asking for complete code since I'm eager to find the exact solution myself (I'd like to get better at programming and not copy+paste) and a clue for where to search would help me out already. (By the way, I am a newbie to programming).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `and a lot more` is not helping. You should clearly explain what is the point of the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Are the sequences allowed to overlap? I.e., what would be the longest repetition in String `"aaaaaaaa"`? I have a feeling that the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm) may be useful when solving this problem.

Comment: explain the question clearly

Comment: @NiVeR a lot more basically means there is a lot more I need to do with this class, but the mentioned problem is the one I'm seeking a clue for on the internet.

Comment: for a newbie you have chosen quite a problem. As mentioned by others, try defining the problem better. with different inputs and desired output.

Comment: I have been programming a brute force method now to find all the repetitions in a string, count them, counting chars between repetitions and so on and so forth. Will consider posting my solution here since it's super easy to understand even for beginners.

Comment: @gagan Singh input: abc12dhabc53abc output: abc, 3 times, length 3, chars in between: 4;2  if there's a quick algorithm which functions here I'd appreciate a hint at it.